# Why Visual C++ makes difference on noexcept of destructor according to /EHsc?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, noexcept

I saw the following sentence in [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec).

> Any user-defined destructor is `noexcept(true)` by default, unless the declaration specifies otherwise, or the destructor of any base or member is `noexcept(false)`.

To know whether Visual C++ 2015 confirm this or not, I tried the following example.

```
#include <iostream>

class Test1 { public: ~Test1() = default; };
class Test2 { public: ~Test2() { } };
class Test3 { public: Test3() { } ~Test3() { } };

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "Test1: " << noexcept(Test1().~Test1()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Test2: " << noexcept(Test2().~Test2()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Test3: " << noexcept(Test3().~Test3()) << std::endl;
}
```

Result:

```
C:\Users\***>cl test.cpp
....

/out:test.exe
test.obj

C:\Users\***>test
Test1: true
Test2: false
Test3: false
```

However, when I turn on `/EHsc` switch which enables exceptions, the result is changed.

```
C:\Users\***>cl test.cpp /EHsc
...

/out:test.exe
test.obj

C:\Users\***>test
Test1: true
Test2: true
Test3: false
```

Why did it happen?

Comment: This is unrelated, but just to not offend the eye to much, maybe you could write the unevaluated expression as `std::declval<T&>().~T()`? Otherwise it looks too much like instant undefined behaviour (even though it is technically correct).